# Working with ieee format numbers in ARM

Tags: assembly, format, arm, cpu-registers, ieee

I'm trying to write an ARM program that will convert an ieee number to a TNS format number.  TNS is a format used by some super computers, and is similar to ieee but different.  I'm trying  to use several masks to place the three different "part" of the ieee number in separate registers so I can move them around accordingly.  Here is my unpack subroutine:

```
UnpackIEEE
    LDR r1, SMASK   ;load the sign bit mask into r1 
    LDR r2, EMASK   ;load the exponent mask into r2
    LDR r3, GMASK   ;load the significand mask into r3
    AND r4, r0, r1  ;apply sign mask to IEEE and save into r4
    AND r5, r0, r2  ;apply exponent mask to IEEE and save into r5
    AND r6, r0, r3  ;apply significand mask to IEEE and save into r6
    MOV     pc, r14     ;return
```

And here are the masks and number declarations so you can understand:

```
IEEE        DCD 0x40300000  ;2.75 decimal or 01000000001100000000000000000000 binary
SMASK       DCD 0x80000000  ;Sign bit mask
EMASK       DCD 0x7F800000  ;Exponent mask
GMASK       DCD 0x007FFFFF  ;Significand mask
```

When I step through with the debugger, the results I get are not what I expect after working through it on paper. EDIT: What I mean, is that after the subroutine runs, registers 4, 5, and 6 all remain 0.  I can't figure out why the masks are not working.  I think I do not fully understand how the number is being stored in the register or using the masks wrong.  Any help appreciated.  If you need more info just ask.

EDIT:  entry point:  Very simple, just trying to get these subroutines working.

```
ENTRY

    LDR r1, IEEE    ;load IEEE num into r1
    BL  UnpackIEEE  ;call unpack sub
    SWI     SWI_Exit    ;finish
```

Comment: What does your calling code look like?

Comment: I posted a solution to a similar issue here:

[Stackoverflow.com Arm Number Conversion Program][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792564/arm-number-conversion-program/15397860#15397860

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
LDR r1, IEEE    ;load IEEE num into r1
```

From the looks of your unpacking routine, it looks like you want to load the number into `r0`, not `r1`. `r1` gets clobbered on the first line of your unpacking routine:

```
UnpackIEEE
    LDR r1, SMASK   ;load the sign bit mask into r1
```