# Need help converting IEEE to TNS in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm, ieee-754

So I am currently creating a code for my Computer Organizations class and we were required to program a Middleware that took an IEEE value and it's equivalent TNS value, and converted them to their respective opposites (e.g. TNS converted to IEEE; IEEE converted to TNS.) Afterwords we are to compare our answers to the originals to check if they are indeed equal. Here is my code:

```
    AREA        IEEEAndTNS, CODE, READONLY;
          ENTRY

                 ADR r1, TNS                ;
                 ADR r2, IEEE           ;
                 BL convertToIEEE       ;
                 BL convertToTNS        ;
                 CMP r2, r5             ;
                 BLEQ   compareIEEE     ;
    Done         B Done                 ;

    convertToIEEE   AND r9, r1, #&FF000000  ;
                    LSR r10, r1, #1         ;
                    AND r10, r10, #&FF      ;
                    LSL r10, r10, #1        ;
                    SUB r10, r10, #256      ;
                    ADD r10, r10, #127      ;
                    LSR r10, r10, #23       ;
                    AND r11, r1, #&CF0000   ;
                    LSL r11, r11, #8        ;
                    ORR r5, r9,r11          ;
                    ORR r5, r5, r10         ;
                    BX  lr                  ;

    convertToTNS    AND r9, r2, #&00        ;
                    AND r10, r2, #&FF000000 ;
                    SUB r10, r10, #127      ;
                    ADD r10, r10, #256      ;
                    LSL r10, r10, #22       ;
                    AND r11, r2, #&CF00     ;
                    LSR r11, r11, #9        ;
                    ORR r6, r9,r11          ;
                    ORR r6, r6, r10         ;
                    BX  lr                  ;

    compareIEEE     CMP r1, r6              ;
                    BLEQ    Done            ;

    IEEE            DCD &4400C800           ;
    TNS             DCD &00C80112           ;

            END
```

My overall problem with this program is that I don't know why they are not equaling each other, because from what I see when I debug it, the registers I'm comparing are set to zero, and of course neither answer will equal that. With this homework due by the end of today, I need huge help!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792564/arm-number-conversion-program#15397860

Comment: So write thing thing in C first to access the bits of the IEEE number, twiddle them about, and output a TNS number. Once you've got the logic right, convert to assembly.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing args and return values between different parts of your code correctly?  [`ADR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/Babcjaii.html) puts an address into a register, but I don't see any LDR instructions in either function.  You don't have any loops, so can't you just single-step through the entire program in a debugger that highlights register values that changed since the last stop?  (e.g. gdb with `layout reg`).